# Django models unique bank cheque number 6 digits

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I try to set unique 6 digit cheque number by help of django doc. but still i dont want desired result means it accept any number or character but i want this will accept only 6 integer and also make sure that number should be unique for all users

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid4
import string
from string import digits

class Mvouchar(models.Model):
cheque_no = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
dated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

    def save(self):
        if not self.cheque_no:
            self.cheque_no = id_generator()
            while Mvouchar.objects.filter(cheque_no=self.cheque_no).exists():
                self.cheque_no = id_generator()
                self.dated = datetime.now()
        super(Mvouchar, self).save()    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.related:
            return self.related.relation.username.title()
        else:
            return 'no related!'
    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Single Cheque Multiple Vouchar Of Users"
```

views.py

```
def mvouchar(request):
            if request.method == "POST":
                userdata = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
                accountdata = Signs.objects.get(relation_id=userdata.id)
        chq_no = request.POST['chequeno']
        mini = Mvouchar(related_id=accountdata.id,  cheque_no = chq_no)
                mini.save()
                messages.success(request, "Your Cheque is Created") 
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/mvouchar/")           
            return render(request, 'cheque/mvouchar.html', {})
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is standard practice to use forms for such example, but still i considered your example and gave my solution. Hope this works for you.

models.py:

```
##change modelfield type
class Mvouchar(models.Model):
  cheque_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(6)], unique=True)
```

views.py:

```
def mvouchar(request):
            if request.method == "POST":
                userdata = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
                accountdata = Signs.objects.get(relation_id=userdata.id)
        chq_no = request.POST['chequeno']
        ##verify chq_no
        if len(chq_no)==6 and chq_no.isdigit():
           if Mvouchar.objects.filter(cheque_no =chq_no):
              ##raiseError chq_no is already exists and return
           ##your further code
        else:
           ##raiseError chq_no is wrongly typed
```

Comment: thanks alot Nagesh Mhapadi for understanding my problem and provide a simple solution that work like magic for me...

Comment: but still i would recommend you to through forms. Once you get it, it will be very easy to implement such things. Django forms documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

Comment: hey hear am getting error cheque_no is not define but i have cheque_no in my models whats going wrong hear

Comment: if Mvouchar.objects.all(cheque_no =chq_no):

Comment: if you like the solution you can upvote to answer :)

Comment: I do this already but not showing publicly bcoz of less reputation.. on SOF

Comment: ohh! No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ModelForm to validate the posted data. Since you have set `unique=True` on the cheque_no model field, the form will check that for you.

```
class MvoucharForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('cheque_no',)

    def clean_cheque_no(self):
        cheque_no = form.cleaned_data['cheque_no']
        if not cheque_no.isdigit():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter digits only')
        return cheque_no
```

...

```
def mvouchar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MvoucharForm(request.POST(
        if form.is_valid():
            accountdata = Signs.objects.get(relation=request.user)
            mini = form.save(commit=False)
            mini.related = accountdata
            mini.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your Cheque is Created") 
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/mvouchar/")
     else:
         form = MvoucharForm()
     return render(request, 'cheque/mvouchar.html', {'form': form})
```

And don't forget to use `form` in the template, especially `{{ form.errors }}`.

Comment: sorry but i dnt use forms till now and i dnt have much knowledge about it. plz can u suggest how can form work

Comment: is this html forms or form.py

Comment: i can not understand this change is done in models.py or make another form like form.py what can i do

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You can put the form wherever you like, but forms.py is standard. The documentation covers forms completely and you should definitely read it, but my code should work as is.

Comment: i want to know what changes i do in models.py.... and you provided code first for forms.py n second is for views.py am i getting right or not